# Nested prepared statements and free_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Can someone explain why `free_result` after a while loop on a nested prepared statement causes `bind_result` to not update values as intended?

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("select col1 from table1 inner join ...");
$stmt -> bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt -> bind_result($col1);
$stmt -> execute() or die();
$stmt -> store_result();

$stmt2 = $mysqli -> prepare("select col2, col3 from table2 where col4 = ?");
$stmt2 -> bind_param("i", $col1);
$stmt2 -> bind_result($col2, $col3);

while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
    $stmt2 -> execute() or die();
    $stmt2 -> store_result();
    while ($stmt2 -> fetch()) {
        echo $col2 .",";
    }
    $stmt2 -> free_result(); // <== Works fine without this line
    echo "---";
}
$stmt -> close();
$stmt2 -> close();
```

If I remove `free_result`, I get the expected output, let's say:

`1,2,---3,4,5,---6,7,---`

If I leave it, the last result of the first run on the parent loop repeats like so:

`1,2,---2,2,2,---2,2,---`

I can't find the answer in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php) ... It seems counter-intuitive since the results are retained instead of being freed.

Here's an executable [example](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/58df996476e597e3a3b7fb6d8f3fd277/php/php8/a395e8199716576bbf8e47726ea246e5/)

Comment: What happens if you move the entire `$stmt2` grouping inside the while loop? Ie. the `prepare`, `bind_param`, and `bind_result`? On a side note, executing SQL statements within a loop can be problematic for performance reasons. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @waterloomatt It works fine, but I'm not sure why. Besides, that means that the statement will be prepared as many times as the parent loop runs. One application would be: a user looks for orders, each order may contain several products, several payments, etc... I could use `INNER/LEFT JOIN` instead but it would significantly increase the size of the data returned by the database, and make the PHP logic more complex to handle the data received. I have applications where it'll be much easier to maintain with nested statements. So I'm trying to understand why `free_result` causes issues.

Comment: Looks interesting and I would have investigated if only it had a proper MCVE. Although I *can* create an MCVE for you, for the life of me I won't understand why it should be a burden on a person who helps, not on a person who asks for help

Comment: @YourCommonSense Agreed. I've added an example to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for [`bind_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> All columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch().

If you move the `bind_result()` call to the appropriate place it will work:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select col1 from table1");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1);
$stmt->store_result();

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("select col2, col3 from table2 where col4 = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $col1);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->bind_result($col2, $col3);
    $stmt2->store_result();
    while ($stmt2->fetch()) {
        echo $col2 .",";
    }
    $stmt2->free_result();
    echo "---";
}
$stmt->close();
$stmt2->close();
```

The reason for this is that `mysqli_stmt::free_result()` asks mysqlnd to free up all result variables. The references are released, but neither the variables nor their values are not destroyed by PHP. They are just unbound.

You can either stop using `mysqli_stmt::free_result()` (which you probably should do anyway) or bind the result variables after every execution.